# UITableViewCell indexPath.section issue on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I am trying to add an image next to the cell text in the 8th row. My issue is that it doesn't entering inside `(indexPath.row == 9)` method while I have put breakpoint I get this value from `indexPath.row = {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}`. So please where would be my issue?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [data count]; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
  if (!cell)
  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleValue1) reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];

    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bakiyem-cell-bg.png"]];
    img.x = 10.;
    img.y = -6.;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:img];
    [img release];

    //
    cell.textLabel.font = [Constants regularFontWithSize:24.];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [Constants textGrayColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [Constants mediumFontWithSize:24.];
}

cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = indexPath.row == 4 ? [UIColor colorWithRed:218./255. green:0 blue:37./255. alpha:1] : [Constants textGrayColor];

   //My issue
 if (indexPath.row == 9) {

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info-logo.png"];   
 }

//
NSDictionary *dic = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"value1"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"value2"];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really should be

```
if (indexPath.row == 7) {
```

Because you only have one row.

If the break point is still not entering your if statement, then add some more logging around it to see what is going one.

Like how about if you try

```
NSLog(@"row = %i", indexPath.row);
if (indexPath.row == 7) {
    NSLog(@"In if statement for row = %i", indexPath.row);
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info-logo.png"];
    NSLog(@"My image=%@",myImage);
    cell.imageView.image = myImage;
}
```

What shows up in NSLog?

Comment: it starts from row=0 to row=9

Comment: So you get row=7 in there?  Then you if block should get entered. Try and NSLog in there too.

Comment: It started to pass inside the `if` statement. I don't know why and how?

Comment: So if you update to add the NSLog I just added in my answer - do you get that statement logged in the if block?

Comment: Yes which is very interesting!!

Comment: Cool - so the issue must be with - `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info-logo.png"];`, right? Double check that info-logo.png is valid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45490/discussion-between-cem-and-ansible)

Answer (score 0):

try it with `indexPath.section == 7`. Or probably `indexPath.row == 7` as Cem has written in the comment.

Comment: I have tried with different number but there is not any images.

Comment: @Cem How many sections do you have? I think you might mean ` if (indexPath.row == 9)` (Or 7 as user2509601 says.)

Comment: @Cem How is your configuration for - `-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`and
`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Comment: @Cem so you have to it with `indexPath.row == 7`. Then first try it with a `NSLog` inside the if statment. So if it enters the if statment you can also check that the `UIImage` is not `nil` with the help of a breakpoint.

Comment: It is not entering inside the `if` statment :|

Comment: try adding a NSLog(@"COUNT: %i",[data count]) before the return in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Answer (score 0):

- The eight row has an index of 7
- You probably mean `indexPath.row` instead of `indexPath.section`
- If you want to customize `UITableViewCell`s, please use custom cells

Comment: I have tried 'indexPath.row' but it didn't work. Also I have used breakpoint now and I get `{length = 2, path = 0 - 0}`.

Comment: I don't want to customize the whole cell I just want to put an image in one of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 9 rows inside 1 section, or 9 sections and in each section 1 row?

For the first case use:
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
      return 1 ;
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section==0)
    {
           return 9;
    }
  }

For the second case;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 9 ;
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
    }

Also, in cellForRowAtIndexPath method use:

In the first case:  indexPath.row==9
In the second case: indexPath.section==0

Answer (score 0):

You should have atleast 9 rows is data array in the following method and indexPath.row = {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} mean you are in 0th row of 0th section. If you return hard code 9 in number of rows method then it will enter in  (indexPath.row == 8)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{    return [data count]; }
```